# Install gradle for using in cordova build android

Tags: android, cordova, build.gradle

I have installed cordova and android sdk on linux mint 17, and downloaded gradle 2.4 (bin) and extracted it and set path to it, now I can get gradle -v from terminal, its ok, but when i want to build cordova :

```
cordova build
```

it starts to download gradle 2.2....

how i can set it to use current gradle 2.4 insteed downloading older version?

> gradle -v

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-05-05 08:09:24 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     5c9c3bc20ca1c281ac7972643f1e2d190f2c943c

Groovy:       2.3.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.4 compiled on April 29 2014
JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-24-generic i386
```

Comment: did u find out how? I am facing the same issue..

Comment: no, then i tried intel xdk for creating cordova web application, it is free and you can build your android app on the fly.

Answer (score 17):

I had figured out the reason:
See the code `GradleBuilder.prototype.prepEnv` in [$PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/bin/templates/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js#L159)。

A quick fix :

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///local/path/to/gradle-2.4-all.zip
cordova run android
```

Notice:

1. This will unzip to `$USER_HOME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.4-all/5i28vc5j9c3ssbtreg4518ujvp/gradle-2.4` .
2. `export` command must always be executed before run cordova.

If the network is slow, you download gradle-2.2.1-all.zip manually, then use this method once.

Also, you can change GradleBuilder.js's code or request a [enhancement/issue](http://cordova.apache.org/contribute/issues.html).

Comment: it make sense, but can't we configure gradle version with [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle) ?

Comment: Thanks only this worked export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///local/path/to/gradle-2.4-all.zip
cordova run android