# Cordova build changes distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file

Tags: cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I keep getting the following build exception when I run

```
 cordova run android --verbose
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
  >   Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

The reason for this is the line being changed when I run the cordova build command from;

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1.0-all.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

Any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As could be guessed, there is a script that is being run behind the scene when you issue the "Cordova build android" command.  This script needs to be found in order to see the config specified for Gradle version.

You must go and check the following js file:

`$PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js`

Then find the line including the following variable in the file:

```
GradleBuilder.prototype.prepEnv
```

And check the distributionUrl variable:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
```

That's what you are looking for and what you need to change to gradle-2.10-all.zip URL;

Now you can run the build command, and there you go!

inspired from the following SO; 
[install gradle for using in cordova build android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413485/install-gradle-for-using-in-cordova-build-android)

Comment: Recreating the project for Android will end in the same situation but this is a nice solution for now.. I checked the master branch for the GradleBuilder.js file on GitHub and it's changed to gradle-2.13-all.zip. The next cordova release will probably also fix this.

Comment: Thank you, shamaleyte! Now I just need to find a place to restores the clumps of hair I've been tearing out for the last several days.

Comment: @brianfit, let us all know if you find a solution for restoring the clumps of hair :))

Comment: Any ideas on how to use the **globally installed gradle version** instead of this method? Because all contents from the `platforms/android` folder is auto-generated by Cordova every time the platform is recreated. Cordova-android 6.3.0 uses gradle 3.3 which is too old.

Comment: In my case I had to also edit: $PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/StudioBuilder.js:                                                                                 under StudioBuilder.prototype.prepEnv = function (opts) { ...                                    var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip';

Comment: Changing the Gradle Distribution url in both StudioBuilder.js and GradleBuilder.js files worked for me.

Answer (score 41):

I think is better to export the variable `CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL`

Example:

```
export
CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

If you are using a Mac, for example, add the export command in to the `.bash_profile`

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Used this solution for a long time and worked great. However recently was getting issues with a newer version. I forgot that I used this and had to go back to my .bash_profile and update to newer version to fix it. (>_<)

Comment: This is the best and quick solution.

Comment: If you are using windows, export would not works. Use setx instead, like below-        >setx CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.4.1-all.zip

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE: 21 May 2017**

Ok, this was a really nasty issue and I felt compelled to write complete instructions to fix in the hope it saves others the hours I wasted on it. The following is a combination of googling, reading the accepted answer, and working things out from trial and error.

Before you do anything else.. make sure you close **Docker** if it is running. A symptom is that in Android Studio, the emulator load dialog just silently vanishes. If you ran from the app start command, your application is simply left waiting to connect to device (message issued).

Assuming you have done that and still not working, read on.

**Optional (maybe)**: fyi only - Personally, I used [SDK Man](http://sdkman.io/) to install a matching version of Gradle on my machine.

Assume you have already got a working Android Studio emulator with Marshmallow or Nougat (or both).

In my case, I was then trying to get Cordova to work.

Depending on whether you wish to start over (recommended) then:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

**First** a download is needed. Download the following according to your OS:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-windows.zip

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-linux.zip

(I was running on Mac, so downloaded:)

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip

Unzip it, and copy the `templates` folder into `/Users/arcseldon/Library/Android/sdk/tools`

**Explanation:** See the logic inside `module.exports.check_gradle` function, declared under `platforms/android/cordova/check_reqs.js` to understand how it is trying to derive the path for the gradle wrapper. This co-erces it.

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/arcseldon/Library/Android/sdk
```

I could see a `tools` subdirectory, but no `templates` folder inside that. 
So copy the `templates` folder from the downloaded and extracted zip, and paste it inside `$ANDROID_HOME/tools`

You should finish with a path hierarchy that includes:

```
/Users/arcseldon/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

This now satisfies the path search from the script perspective.

**Secondly**, check your cordova application for platforms/android/build.gradle, and search for the `gradleVersion`.

`task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.14.1'
}`

For your version, download from URL as follows:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-X.Y.Z-all.zip

replacing X, Y, Z as needed to match your version.

In my case,

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

other examples:

https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip

Then, once downloaded, place on your local drive and reference with ENV. variable. eg. (changing to your version)

```
export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///Users/myusername/temp/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

**Explanation:** If you run a search you'll find this environment variable is an optional override for this env. variable.
See the variable assignment for `check_gradle`, declared under `platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/GradleBuilder.js`

Now just run:

```
cordova run android --verbose
```

All going well, everything should now "just work" for Android. In my case, iOS was out of the box - but I did use Xcode 8.2 instead of Xcode 8.3 for other reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination, quite helpful to understand and get things running ... In my case the `platforms/android/cordova/check_reqs.js` is located in `platforms/android/cordova/lib/check_reqs.js` however (windows).

Comment: @PediT. thanks for feedback, pleased to hear you made progress.

Comment: I also open Android Studio then "Build > Clean Project" from the menu then I can build using AndroidStudio also... Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 6):

This happened to us because we accidentally let Android Studio build our cordova project causing endless errors.

Save yourself while you can:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/ProjectBuilder.js

around line 232 you will see:

var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.3-all.zip';

adjust the gradle to whatever you need.

Example:
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip';

Answer (score 2):

You can try out the following to resolve the issue,

On Windows, Change `File -> Settings -> Builds,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle home` path

On Mac OS, Change `Android Studio -> Preferences -> Builds,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle home` path

Else use default gradle wrapper and edit `Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties file's distributionUrl` like this:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Comment: The problem is actually that I am not able to make it possible with your "else" solution. The "Use default gradle wrapper(recommended" option is selected. And when I run the cordova command, the changed distributionUrl is reverted back to its former version.  So sad.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me because I wasn't building with the latest version of cordova-android. so:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@latest
```

Take not of the `@latest` directive.
Also be sure to update download the latest version of gradle and include it in the appropriate directory, as pointed out in the other answers.

Comment: Can also update the cordova-android version in your package.json

Answer (score 1):

Please check with Environment Variable.

My Computer > Properties > System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables... > Under 'System variables' find following setting & try to change it as per your gradle version.

```
CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Just save the settings and reopen command windows. And try to build again.

Answer (score -1):

Try just open the file project/platforms/android/build.gradle and update

dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X'
}
and 
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = 'X.X'
}

see the reference here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle 
to change the X.X

Comment: build.gradle is a generated file in cordova. You'll be doing this constantly