# Cordova won't compile android: classpath dependancy gradle 2.2.0 Alpha1

Tags: android, cordova, maven

I'm afraid this won't be a well-formed question, because I don't even know where to begin. Updated my Android platform to 5.1.1. Attempted to run **cordova build android** but it spits an error:

> - What went wrong:
>     A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>     Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>     Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha1/gradle-2.2.0-alpha1.pom
>          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-alpha1/gradle-2.2.0-alpha1.jar
>      Required by:
>          :android:unspecified

If I poke around at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle I see indeed, there is no 2.2.0 directory. But I'm a newb to dependancies and the Android platform, and that "Unspecified" doesn't give me a clue where to begin looking for the problem let alone how to fix it.

My Gradle Wrapper:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

I tried changing that 2.2.1 to 2.2.0 but nope -- that dog didn't bite. And there's this in my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha1'

    }
```

My plugins are:

```
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 0.8.1 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplayservices 19.0.3 "Google Play Services for Android"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.2 "StatusBar"
nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing 5.0.11 "SocialSharing"
```

Comment: Thanks to [Shamaleyte's answer to this identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125496/cordova-build-changes-distributionurl-in-gradle-wrapper-properties-file), problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

use  try

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
      //  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.X.X' // your verison

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Pong, but the issue was resolved with this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37242313/4158458