# Android Studio keeps resetting Gradle version when trying to install plugin

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle

I'm fairly new to using android studio, and I can't seem to wrap my head around what i'm doing wrong.

I'm currently trying to install the [Ping Plugin from Cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ping), now everytime I try and install it I get the error message

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.4. Current version is 4.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/sam/Development/Apps/ghost/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.4-all.zip

So from here I go to `File > Project Structure > Project` and change the Gradle version to 4.4 and the Android Plugin version to 3.1.1. I then let android studios build and do what it needs to do.

From here I check the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and can confirm it says `4.4-all.zip`.

I then try and reinstall the plugin, it then throws the same error, so I check my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file and it resets itself back to 4.1!

Am I doing something stupid?

Again i'm very new to Android Studios, so apologies if i've missed anything.

Incase it helps, some extra details are

OS - macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Homebrew - Global machine Gradle version 4.7

Android OS - 6.0.1

Cordova - 8.0.0

**EDIT**

Something else I have noticed, If I go into the `.gradle` folder in my application, and remove the 4.1 folder and try to install the plugin, it automatically recreates the 4.1 folder and uses it?

Also i've now noticed it has this behaviour every time I run any cordova command, including `cordova build android`

Comment: what is your Android Studio version?

Comment: @SomeshKumar 3.1.1

Comment: what is gradle version in build.gradle (project level) file? for eg: I have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'`

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'`

Comment: if you have version `3.1.2` then your android studio version should be `3.1.2` and earlier said you're using AS v3.1.1... Make sure you are using default gradle wrapper in Open File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.

Comment: @SomeshKumar, found the answer. Will post as an answer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169656/discussion-between-somesh-kumar-and-s-r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else experiencing this behaviour, once I found out that it was any cordova command that was causing the gradle to reset, It was easy to find the answer.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125496/cordova-build-changes-distributionurl-in-gradle-wrapper-properties-file)

Basically there is a distributionUrl located inside the `GradleBuilder.js` file that kept on resetting my gradle back to 4.1. This needed to be changed to 4.4 and the build and plugins worked straight away!

Answer (score 1):

"Moral of this particular story, for me anyway, don't update Android Studio for no good reason" - This should be made the 11th Commandment.  I was able to fix this issue by deleting the /platform/android folder and re-installing it making sure not to click on any "highly recommend" upgrade options.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above and listed in the path below,

[Cordova build changes distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125496/cordova-build-changes-distributionurl-in-gradle-wrapper-properties-file)

I found that on Android Studio 3.1.2, it is necessary to update not just GradleBuilder.js as per all previous advice, but also StudioBuilder.js.

Just to be clear, both files are in the same directory:
$PROJECT_ROOT/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders/

and the text to be changed in this instance is 
'https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip' to
'https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'

Moral of this particular story, for me anyway, don't update Android Studio for no good reason, as it'll take up 3 hours of your day fixing sh*t. Wait till Cordova has been upgraded to suit before even thinking about it.