# How to Update SDK and Gradle in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, sdk, build.gradle

I am newbie and just use cordova app, when first use `cordova` to build `android`, error message appears to update `SDK`.

> How to update `SDK` in `cordova`? in display error, from 25.0.3 upgrade to 26.0.2
>   [Display Error Update `SDK`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RjRc.png)

Then I think, I can open cordova app using `android studio` to update its `SDK`, after i open in android studio, SDK succeed in update but appear new problem, that gradlenya also need to update.

> How to update Gradle in Cordova? in display error, from 4.1 upgrade to 4.4
>   [Display Error Update Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt87x.png)

Where i can setting to update `SDK` and Gradel in `Cordova`? 
Thanks before.

Comment: Hi @gautam-surani, can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: @NullPointer - android studio has been updated with gradle 4.4 and have update from
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip, but when build android, that gradle back version 4.1

Comment: still error when gradle i update manual

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37125496/1081909

Comment: I have try it and it does not work, i have android platform rm android then install platform android again, but it does not work.

Comment: thank your response