# Gradle distributionUrl changes with 'ionic cordova run android' to older version, build failure

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've updated my Gradle distributionUrl to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip from gradle-4.1-all.zip, but when I run `ionic cordova run android` it reverts itself back to the 4.1-all.zip file. This happens around the time where the terminal comes to:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Subproject Path: app
```

which then results in

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\....\platforms\android\CordovaLib\build.gradle' line 40

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project':CordovaLib'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
 > Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 4.1...
```

Line 40 in this case is `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

The issue I'm seeing is that the Gradle version is reverting itself back to the previous version. How can I get this to stay at version 6.1.1? Is there something wrong with the `com.android.library` plugin that I should be fixing?

my gradle dependencies are:

```
classpath 'com.andorid.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
```

my `ionic info`:

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\bg21562\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.3
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.1
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.11.3
    npm               : 6.11.3
    OS                : Windows 10
Environment Variables:
    ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Bg21562\AppData\Local\Android\SDK
Misc:
    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle versions are located in several locations, as it turns out.

In order to fix this, I found the distributionUrl as a variable in the following locations:
`platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\StudioBuilder.js` and `platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js`

Both of these files include

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip';
```

which of course, needed to be replaced with 6.1.1-all.zip

Make sure to also replace the gradle-wrapper.properties file with the 6.1.1 gradle version.

I also found an option to add an export variable for CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL into the bash profile:
`export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Best answers found here: [Cordova build changes distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125496/cordova-build-changes-distributionurl-in-gradle-wrapper-properties-file/37242313)

Comment: export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=https 
  ://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip

Worked for me. Thank you

Comment: For windows powershell users like me, the equivalent command is:
 $env:CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL='https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip'
It worked for me, Thank you.