# 'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cordova, gradle, ionic3

I'm building app using Ionic and when I'm on the last step which is to release the apk for my app, I'm facing some problem with the `ANDROID_HOME` error. I've set it manually and problem solved.

But then coming up with another error on the cmd that saying

> CordovaError: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio

I found a solution for that by referring to this discussion [install gradle for using in cordova build android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413485/install-gradle-for-using-in-cordova-build-android/45853789#45853789)

After all been set, I tried to run my command again `ionic cordova build --release android` but then I'm having the error **'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Comment: There can be a reason like you might have accidentally changed path for ionic...

Comment: Try to revert back your PATH environment and check. If it works, maybe a problem with adding gradle in your PATH variable.

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar I'm trying to revert it back but my bad, I did not store the path before I change it and now I don't remember the original path :(

Comment: @Ashwani will reinstall ionic can solve the path problem?

Comment: yes it surely will and it wont hamper your project also..install it globally

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar I've successful reverting the PATH back to it's original path. But the `CordovaError` about gradle is happening again. Do you have any idea about it? Thanks.

Comment: @Emerald, Today only I got same error regarding gradle, I downloaded gradle-4.6 zip and extracted that zip folder into C drive and added that path till bin folder in PATH environment variable.As usual restarted Computer to apply environment path variable changes, and it works for me..

Comment: @PradnyaSinalkar Thanks! It working for me now too.

Comment: Great to hear that..