# gradle: not installed (cordova requirements)

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova

i tried to type :

> cordova requirements

and it is give result as :

> Android Studio project detected
>   Requirements check results for android:
>   Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: installed true
>   Android target: installed android-27,android-26
>   Gradle: not installed
>   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   (node:2392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
>       at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:414:27
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
>       at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>   (node:2392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:2392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

so i tried to install gradle manually. And after the gradle was installed, i tried to type:

> gradle -v

and then it is give result as :

> ------------------------------------------------------------
>   Gradle 4.7
>   ------------------------------------------------------------
>   Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
>   Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c
>   Groovy:       2.4.12
>   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
>   JVM:          1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation 25.162-b12)
>   OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

it means the gradle was installed. But when i try to cek the requirements again with type :

> cordova requirements

it still give me same result like before as :

> Android Studio project detected
>   Requirements check results for android:
>   Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: installed true
>   Android target: installed android-27,android-26
>   Gradle: not installed
>   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   (node:2392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
>       at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:414:27
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
>       at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>   (node:2392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:2392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

And after that, i tried again to install gradle in cmd with command :

> npm install gradle

and it is give result as :

> +gradle@1.0.9
>   added 20 packages from 14 contributors in 182.961s
>   [!] 13 vurnerabilities found [4232 packages audited]
>   severity 2 low | 11 moderate
>   run 'npm audit' for more detail

and then i tried again to check requirements, and it is gave me same result as:

> cordova requirements

it still give me same result like before as

> Android Studio project detected
>   Requirements check results for android:
>   Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>   Android SDK: installed true
>   Android target: installed android-27,android-26
>   Gradle: not installed
>   Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   (node:2392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Some of requirements check failed
>       at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\cli.js:414:27
>       at _fulfilled (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
>       at C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
>       at flush (C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
>   (node:2392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:2392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code

when i check again the version of gradle with type :

> gradle -v

it still give the same version as 4.7 with the result :

> ------------------------------------------------------------
>   Gradle 4.7
>   ------------------------------------------------------------
>   Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
>   Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c
>   Groovy:       2.4.12
>   Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
>   JVM:          1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation 25.162-b12)
>   OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64

my question is, why the gradle still not installed?
please help me, i dont know how to fix it again.
Thank you !

im use:
cordova : 8.0.0
node :8.11.2
java jdk : 1.8.0
gradle : 4.7
windows 7 64-bit

Comment: What happens if you run `cordova build `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413485/install-gradle-for-using-in-cordova-build-android

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42639125/6587502 also

Comment: @deathangel908 it give result as http://prntscr.com/jlj0xb
i guess it caused by gradle not installed, right?

Comment: @AshutoshSagar ok i will try it. thanks

Comment: Can you debug this thing? I mean Cordova seems like a thing that runs js inside of node, you can set a breakpoint inside of `check_recks.js:139`. Also, you can create the issue inside to [cordova](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android), because when gradle not found Cordova should at least stays so instead of throwing `.length` of undefined exception

Answer (score 1):

Kindly add path to your system variable. i.e
Open system -> advanced -> Environment Variable
under system variable section click on path and then click on edit button
their add your path to gradle/bin.

Comment: For a more complete version of this answer, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43480076/ionic-2-error-could-not-find-an-installed-version-of-gradle-either-in-android/43692039#answer-45070795